# Flutter http.get(url) throws an Exception on resp code 403 when built for web, returns a response if built for native. Bug?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter **web** http throws a http.ClientException on a response with status other than 200. The exception has a message "XMLHttpRequest error". How do I get the actual response body and statusCode? Examples online say use response.statusCode but exception is thrown before response is returned.

```
try {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(apiEndpoint);
   final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer token"});
   print(response.statusCode); **// THIS LINE IS NEVER EXECUTED IF RESP CODE IS NOT 200**
} catch(e) {
   print(e); // Was it 403, 404 or 500???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The case that you described

> XMLHttpRequest error

occurs because of the CORS, which throws an Exception rather than returning the result.

So to catch that, you can look at the sample code below.

```
try {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(apiEndpoint);
  final response =
      await http.get(uri, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer token"});
  debugPrint("ResponseCode: ${response.statusCode}");
} catch (e) {
  if (e is http.ClientException && e.message == "XMLHttpRequest error.") {
    debugPrint("CORS error.");
    return;
  }
  debugPrint("Exception: ${e.toString()}");
}
```

If you want to disable CORS in Flutter Web, you can achieve it by running your project with the following command:

> flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"

As for the rest of the case, the ***response.statusCode*** should be sufficient.

Comment: It's not due to CORS, API responses that return status code 200 do not cause an exception.

Comment: If there is no exception, you can just use a response.statusCode to get the status code.

Comment: Must be AI bot generated..

Answer (score -1):

In Flutter, the `http` package does throw a `ClientException` when a network error occurs, but it does not throw this exception for HTTP status codes other than 200 by default. Instead, it returns the response with the non-200 status code along with the response body. You can access the status code and response body directly without the need for exception handling.

Here is the modified code:

```
try {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(apiEndpoint);
  final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer token"});

  // Check if the response status code is not 200 (OK)
  if (response.statusCode != 200) {
    print('Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
  } else {
    // Handle the successful response here
    print('Successful Response: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
}
```

Comment: But it does throw this exception for me on any response that's not 200 (403 for example) and execution never gets to the if in your example. As I've described in my question..